# My book western digital not recognized on windows after time machine backup

Tags: time-machine, hard-drive

I have an MY BOOK from western digital I used it once for TIME MACHINE BACKUP, now under windows the hard drive is not recognized and theres no way to format it since it not recognized by windows, but it is recognized by mac, how can I format it in mac so it will be recognized in windows once again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by 'not recognized' you mean not able to be mounted, this is because it has been formatted as Mac OS Extended (Journaled) — HFS+.

To be able to read/write to it in Windows, you can format it to FAT.

1. Open Disk Utility and connect your disk.
2. Select the disk and choose the Erase tab.
3. Select MS-DOS (FAT) as the format.

   [image]
4. Click Erase.

<sup>All data on the disk will be lost.</sup>

Comment: I think the last line should be in as big a font as the others = @bmacuser There is no easy way to have a disk with Time Machine data on readable in Windows - you will need a third party Windows tool to read HFS+ disks